# Integer.decode(String s) throws NumberFormatException for some Strings

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "64403F "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

But it works for many inputs like A89B88, 927F66, FFDB58. Can you please help me in understanding what's happening here?

Comment: None of these examples works if you don't add `0x` to them (e.g., `0xA89B88`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `String` that is throwing the `NumberFormatException` ends in white-space `"64403F "`. Call `trim()` on the `String` before you parse it. Using [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
String str = "64403F ";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str.trim(), 16));
```

Or, using [`Integer.decode(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String str = "64403F ";
System.out.println(Integer.decode("0x" + str.trim()));
```

The output is

```
6570047
```